# Symfony2 Doctrine, remove useless array in query

Tags: php, json, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a query in a repository like :

```
        $qb->select('f.state as link')
            ->from('MyProjectBundle:Friend', 'f')
            ->where('CONDITIONS');
        return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

So, this query return the state with you and a friend. In my controller i return :

```
return array('link' => $state);
```

$state is the result of my query. I can only have one result with this query, it's just the state with ONE other user. So, when i check the response, i have (in json) :

```
    {
    "link": [
        {
            "link": 1
        }
    ]    
   }
```

How can i remove the array [] in this json ? It's useless here.. Thanks !

Comment: `return array(current($state));` ?

Comment: Nice ! Answer my question if you want ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As expected ;)
You can use `return array(current($state));`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getSingleScalarResult()` method as explained here :

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#query-result-formats

```
$qb->select('f.state as link')
    ->from('MyProjectBundle:Friend', 'f')
    ->where('CONDITIONS');

return $qb->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();
```